# Get value in formData

Tags: jquery

I created fromData and add variable "act".

how can i alert the "act" value?

```
var form = $(this).closest('form')[0];
var form_data = new FormData(form);
form_data.append('act', "edit");
```

in the example above it should alert "edit"

Comment: Short answer; not easily. There is [`FormData.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get#Browser_compatibility) but it's not widely supportd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_data.get('fielDname')` extracts values. So:

```
alert(form_data.get('act'))
```

**Cautoion:** `.get` not works on IE, Safari and android webView

Comment: Note that this won't work at all in IE, Edge or Safari

Comment: Oh, so is there any other solution?

Comment: If you want to submit a form, use XMLhttp request instead or simply an ajax call with desired data. @Roi